# How to use loop change status in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am very new to this "cogs" thing, I am trying to arrange my whole code into cogs and here I am stuck at the very first part..xd

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from  itertools import cycle
status = cycle(['?help', '?about', '?addbot', 'Deadshot'])
class startup(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Quotient is online!\nUsername: {self.bot.user}")
        self.bot.change_status.start()
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
    async def change_status(self):
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
   
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong!")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(startup(bot))
```

I don't understand why it throw me error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\Desktop\discord bots\quotient\cogs\startup.py", line 13, in on_ready
    self.bot.change_status.start()
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'change_status'
```

Comment: You encounter this error because `Bot` does not have a `change_status` attribute. `Client`, the super-class of `Bot` had a `change_attribute` method a long time, but it has been deprecated for several version and is probably no longer available. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html?highlight=change_status#id37

Answer (score 0):

Theres a much simpler way to do this without having to use discord.ext.tasks

heres my code for it

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):

        statuses = [f'over {len(set(self.client.get_all_members()))} users!', f'over {len(self.client.guilds)} guilds!','Forgot your prefix? @mention me!', 'over your mind']


        displaying = cycle(statuses)

        running = True

        print('\nBlutonium is operational!')
        print(f'logged in as {self.client.user}\n')

        while running:
            current_status = next(displaying)
            await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(name=current_status ,type=3))
            await asyncio.sleep(20)
```

Also you could do this if you want to also change the type

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):

        statuses = [[f'over {len(set(self.client.get_all_members()))} users!', 1], [f'over {len(self.client.guilds)} guilds!', 3],['Forgot your prefix? @mention me!', 3], ['over your mind', 3]]


        displaying = cycle(statuses)

        running = True

        print('\nBlutonium is operational!')
        print(f'logged in as {self.client.user}\n')

        while running:
            current_status = next(displaying)
            await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(name=current_status[0] ,type=current_status[1]))
            await asyncio.sleep(20)
```